# Bind state to context value in React JS

Tags: reactjs, state, react-context, createcontext

I am very new to react. I have two components with two buttons and using context API to for global state. The values are updating in console log but not on the UI

Here is the code

```
App.jsx

import { useContext} from "react"
import Component1 from "./Component1"
import Component2 from "./Component2"
import { CounterContext } from "./CounterContext"
import CounterContextProvider from "./CounterContext"

function App() {
  const context = useContext(CounterContext)
  return <CounterContextProvider>
    <h1>Counter Value: {context.counterValue}</h1>
    <Component1/>
    <Component2/>
    </CounterContextProvider>
  }
  export default App
```

---

```
 Component1.jsx
  import { useContext } from "react"
  import { CounterContext } from "./CounterContext"
  export default function Component1() {
     const context = useContext(CounterContext);
     return <>
       <h1>Component 1</h1>
       <button onClick={context.handleIncrement}>Increment</button>
     </>
  }
```

---

```
Component2.jsx

import { useContext } from "react"
import { CounterContext } from "./CounterContext"
export default function Component2() {
   const context = useContext(CounterContext);
   return <>
    <h1>Component 2</h1>
    <button onClick={context.handleDecrement}>Decrement</button>
   </>
 }
```

---

```
import { createContext, useContext, useState } from "react";

export const CounterContext = createContext({
    counterValue: 10,
    handleIncrement: () => {},
    handleDecrement: () => {}
});

export default function CounterContextProvider({children}) {
   const context =useContext(CounterContext);
   const [counterState, setCounterState] = useState({counterValue: 10})
   
   function incrementValue() {
      console.log(counterState)
      let copiedObject = {...counterState}
      copiedObject.counterValue = copiedObject.counterValue + 1;
      setCounterState({...copiedObject})
   }

   function decrementValue() {
      let copiedObject = {...counterState}
      copiedObject.counterValue = copiedObject.counterValue - 1;
      setCounterState({...copiedObject})
   }

   let ctxValue = {
     counterValue: counterState.counterValue,
     handleIncrement: incrementValue,
     handleDecrement: decrementValue
   }

   return (
      <CounterContext.Provider value={ctxValue}>
          {children}
      </CounterContext.Provider>
   )
}
```

Here is the output image
When I click on increment the value changes in logs but not updated in UI. Is there something I am doing wrong. I want to do this using context API only
[image: Output of project]

Comment: In `App`: this line `const context = useContext(CounterContext)` uses entirely different context than this line `return <CounterContextProvider>`. You can't initialize and use context in the same component

Comment: Thanks @Konrad. I got your point we cannot use useContext where we have initialized the component. I have moved my <h1>Counter Value:{}</h1> to a new component and boom it started working. Thank you very much